# How to check if folder exist inside a directory if not create it using python

Tags: python, ftp, lookup, subdirectory, create-directory

I use the below python script to check if a file exist on the `root` of my ftp server.

```
from ftplib import FTP 
ftp = FTP('ftp.hostname.com')
ftp.login('login', 'password')

folderName = 'foldername'

if folderName in ftp.nlst() :
    print 'YES'
else : print 'NO'
```

How can I modify the above script to look inside a specific folder instead of the `root` directory?

For example, I want to see if a folder name called `foo` exists inside the `www` directory.

The `goal` of my question, is to see if the folder `foo` exists inside the `www` directory, if so print `cool`! if not create a folder called `foo` inside `www`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the hint from Hans! I searched on google for those commandes and I found this link : http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

```
from ftplib import FTP 

ftp = FTP('ftp.hostname.com')
ftp.login('login', 'passwrd')
ftp.cwd('www') # change into 'www' directory

if 'foo' in ftp.nlst() : #check if 'foo' exist inside 'www'
    print 'YES'
    ftp.cwd('foo')  # change into "foo" directory
    ftp.retrlines('LIST') #list directory contents

else : 
    print 'NO'
    ftp.mkd('foo') #Create a new directory called foo on the server.
    ftp.cwd('foo') # change into 'foo' directory
    ftp.retrlines('LIST') #list subdirectory contents

ftp.close() #close connection
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from ftplib import FTP 
ftp = FTP('ftp.hostname.com')
ftp.login('login', 'password')
where      = 'www'
folderName = 'foldername'

if folderName in ftp.nlst(where) :
    print 'YES'
else :
    print 'NO'
```

Just send the directory you want to see in as first argument of `ftp.nlst()`

Comment: `ftp.nlst()` will give you filenames and directories in CWD.

Comment: @TomaszGandor @wtayyeb `ftp.nlst(where)` does not work properly when there is a space in the directory name. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

ftplib is a rather thin wrapper around the FTP protocol. You can look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands to see what the FTP commands do.

Hint: look at CWD, LIST, MKD.

For LIST you will need ftp.retrlines and parse it to see if it is a directory.